# Multiple monitors with multiple different NVidia graphics cards on the same screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to put monitors connected to different graphics cards on the same screen?

I have a setup with two graphics cards (GTX 1080 and GTX 1050 Ti). The idea is to run a total of 4 monitors on that (one 4K monitor on the GTX 1080, and three 1080p monitors on the GTX 1050 Ti). When starting Ubuntu 21.04 with this setup only the 4K monitor on the GTX 1080 shows the Unity desktop. Two of the tree 1080p monitors show a black desktop where the mouse is an X. Hence, I can move my mouse around all the active monitors, but the desktop only shows on the 4K monitor, but not on the others. In the Nvidia X Server Settings application (version `nvidia-driver-495`) the 4K monitor on the GTX 1080 is shown in Configuration "X screen 0" and two of the 1080p monitors are shown in the Configuration "X server 1".

Now, I would like to have them all on one and the same desktop (X screen 0), but the configuration doesn't seem to offer that for some reason, i.e. the 1080p monitor only offers the Configurations: "Disabled", "X screen 1", and "New X screen (requires X restart)".

Is there a way to put all the screens on the same screen, so that they all show the same desktop distributed across all the monitors?

[image: 4K monitor settings]

[image: 1080p monitors settings]

Comment: Try to boot Ubuntu Live (20.04 LTS Desktop) and see if it manages to configure all your monitors to single desktop. If yes, there is a chance you will do this. Another way - try to manualy edit 'X Configuration file' making single X screen.

Comment: Tried it out. It works kind of half-way with the nouveau open source driver. But as soon as I log in, some of the monitors just stop showing the desktop. The mouse is always visible, but I can only sometimes pull windows from one screen over to the other. I still have the window, but some of the monitors just don't show it. I'm kind of confused by this behavior. I would have expected it to "just work" or to "not work at all", but this half-way working'ish thing is strange. I tried other NVidia driver versions as well, but they always create one screen per graphics card. Why is that?

Comment: Did you look at Display Settings while booting Ubuntu Live with nouveau driver?